# Just installed Visual Studio 2015, what language is this code?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a userform created using Visual Studio 2015, I have no idea what the language is.

In my experience VS uses VB (Visual Basic), but this is clearly another language judging from the bracket and semicolon usage.

What language is this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Caesar_Cipher
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *Thomas Shera* is clearly a pseudonym for *Marty McFly*.

Comment: Why does this have 8 upvotes?

Comment: @SterlingArcher high quality questions get more upvotes. Perhaps you should make some higher quality questions if you want "all the votes".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question -- it's asking what language a syntax is.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is very specific about a moment in time. "Recognize this language" is not a good question for stack overflow and is unlikely to help any future users.

Comment: "VS uses VB" - what? Visual Studio is an IDE, which includes a text editor, which *can be used* to write ... anything you want really. VS doesn't "use" a language.

Answer (score 7):

The language is C#.

> C#[note 2] (pronounced as see sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming
>   language encompassing strong typing, imperative, declarative,
>   functional, generic, object-oriented (class-based), and
>   component-oriented programming disciplines. It was developed by
>   Microsoft within its .NET initiative and later approved as a standard
>   by Ecma (ECMA-334) and ISO (ISO/IEC 23270:2006). C# is one of the
>   programming languages designed for the Common Language Infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it looked a bit similar to both C++ and Java.

Comment: @ThomasShera you can create a VB project by selecting VB in the new project window but learning C# is likely to be beneficial in the long-run.

Answer (score 0):

This  is C#  . 
You can start  visual studio 2008 or 2010,  tis may be easy for you .

visual studio supports more than 72 languages